# How to integrate ck-editor with jquery validate?

Tags: php, editor, ckeditor

I would like to Integrate CK-editor with jquery validate, but it not working.

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
        rules: {
            txtckeditor: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            txtckeditor: "This field is required.",
          onkeyup: false,
        onblur: true
});
```

How  to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Before calling the validate try something like:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.txtckeditor.updateElement(); // then your validate call
$("#commentForm").validate({
        rules: {
                 ....
```